# Cannot ssh to server even though rsa_id.pub has been inserted to authorized keys

Tags: ssh

I can ssh to a server using my windows machine. There, I put the ssh key of my Linux machine (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. However, I cannot ssh to the server using my Linux machine:

```
$ ssh xyz@172.16.0.32


sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/xyz/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation
xyz@172.16.0.32: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Edit:

I just applied

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

which did not have an effect on the issue.

Comment: Did you change the permissions of the file to 644?

Comment: thx, check out the edit

Comment: As far as I know , `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (the public key) needs `644` permissions [check this for example](https://nathanos.dev/blog/devops/ssh-key-file-permissions). You can try and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the permissions of `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`:

```
chmod 700 id_rsa*
```

Answer (score 0):

The right permissions are

```
chmod 600 id_rsa         # rw-------
chmod 644 id_rsa.pub     # rw-r--r--
```

or using symbolic permissions:

```
chmod u=rw,go=  id_rsa
chmod u=rw,go=r id_rsa.pub
```

The .pub file is the public key, and it can be readable by anyone. It's only the private key which must have permissions restricted to the owner.